# Netsuite ODBC Error: pyodbc execute is raising `[HY000] The directory name is invalid.` error

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, netsuite, pyodbc

My challenge is to connect to Netsuite using ODBC driver from [Cdata](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/odbc/). I have finished setting up the driver. 
The output for my **`odbcinst -j`:**

```
unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

I am trying to fetch data with this python code:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NetSuite;User=username;Password=passwd')
pcursor = cnxn.cursor()
pcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts")
rows = pcursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Where username and passwd are the credentials for the Netsuite Account. It is however, retuning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odbctest.py", line 5, in <module>
  pcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts")
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] The directory name is invalid. (-1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that `/etc/odbcinst.ini`, `/etc/odbc.ini`, and `/root/.odbc.ini` exist and that they are accessible to the user? It would also help to see the contents of `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and `/etc/odbc.ini` to ensure that you've configured the driver and DSN properly.

Comment: Please include the config files that @JerodJohnson mentioned as well. It is possible that `odbcinst.ini` is pointing to the wrong driver location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the wrong driver name. Make sure that you are accessing the correct values in `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini`.

Comment: Hey
I am new to this space- Python+odbc+netsuite. Does the native NS odbc driver not suffice? I am trying to understand why you needed the Cdata odbc driver.

Thanks